# IF statment inside a IF?

Tags: python, if-statement

Python
How would I make this work? It does not print it.

```
if player1 == "Rock":
    if player2 == "Paper":
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
    if player2 ==  "Scissors":
        print("Player 1 Wins!")
    if player2 == "Rock":
        print("Draw")
```

Comment: well, if player1 ISN'T rock, then none of the other ifs will run...

Comment: opps, sorry i didnt notice

Answer (score 2):

You are missing logical cases.  You need to cover all cases for both player 1 and player 2

```
if player1 == "Rock":
   if player2 == "Paper":
      print("Player 2 Wins")
   elif player2 == "Sissors":
      print("Player 1 Wins")
   elif player2 == "Rock":
      print( "Draw"):
elif player1 == "Paper":
   if player2 == "Paper":
      print("Draw")
   ...
elif player1 == "Sissors":
   if player2 == "Paper":
      print("Player 1 Wins")
   elif player2 == "Rock":
   ...
```

Another option to simplify the logic would be to build a dictionary of your precomputed results

```
win = "Player 1 Wins"
loose = "Player 2 Wins"
tie = "Tie"
results = { "rock": { "paper":loose, "sissors":win, "rock":tie},
            "paper": { "paper":tie, "sissors:":win, "rock":loose},
            "sissors": { "paper":win, "sissors:":tie, "rock":loose} }
```

With the above code you can do something along the lines of

```
results["rock"]["paper"]
'Player 2 Wins'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be complete:

```
if player1 == "Rock":
    if player2 == "Paper":
        print("Player 2 Wins!")
    elif player2 == "Scissors":
        print("Player 1 Wins!")
    elif player2 == "Rock":
        print("Draw")
elif player1 == "Paper":
    # Same overall format different output
elif player1 == "Scissors":
    # Same overall format different output
else:
    print("You must choose Rock, Paper, or scissors")
```